# MFTF Testing for custom module in magento 2.4.3

Tags: testing, magento2.4.3, mftf

How to Test custom module using "MFTF" in **Magento2.4.3**

Recently I uploaded a custom module in the marketplace and the module reject-with these error:-

[image]

I don't know how to resolve these errors so I try to test the module with **"MFTF"**.